# Como configuro el htaccess para la api de woocommerce y la api de wordpress al mismo tiempo?

Tags: wordpress, api, .htaccess, woocommerce

Tengo el siguiente htaccess para usar la API de Wordpress que me funciona perfectamente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Y luego tengo este para la api de Woocommerce que también funciona:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteBase /badamsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /badamsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

El problema es que si uso uno no funciona la API de Wordpress (Error 401 Autorización denegada) y si uso el otro no me funciona la API de Woocommerce (JSON ERROR: Syntax error)

No se como hacer para que funcionen ambas cosas a la vez, agradezco cualquier ayuda.